# Where can I access this research paper on Frechet distance score?

Tags: papers, resource-request, fid-score

[Frechet Inception Distance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08500) is a metric that calculates the distance between feature vectors calculated for real and generated images. It is used in evaluations how good the generated images are.

Consider the following citation of the research paper I want to study in detail, which I think is the first paper on Frechet distance

> Fréchet, Maurice. "Sur la distance de deux lois de probabilité."
> Comptes Rendus Hebdomadaires des Seances de L Academie des Sciences
> 244.6 (1957): 689-692.

I have no clue on where to access the paper.

In general I get PDFs of almost any research paper due to my institute subscriptions in various publishers. But, I cannot see the pdf or contents of this research paper anywhere.

What can I do for accessing this paper?

Comment: The linked paper cites another paper "The Fréchet distance between multivariate normal distributions.", which may be more relevant to you than the paper you're looking for (which is in French). Anyway, even the Wiki article on the _Frechet distance_ mentions the related _Frechet Inception Distance_ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance#As_a_distance_between_probability_distributions_(the_FID_score)), and there's also a main article dedicated to [the FID distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inception_distance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reference in the Google was link to that paper : https://www2.sonycsl.co.jp/person/nielsen/infogeo/Seminar/Frechet-Fondamental-Distance-Wasserstein.pdf

[image]

Comment: Please check the title. Are they same?

Comment: @hanugm, yes, as far as I understand, maybe the location of title was a bit tricky

Comment: And the language is alien to me.

Comment: @hanugm - I am not familiar with French, too. However, some claims are clear due to the similarity between European languages. Seemingly, OCR + NLP model can make a reasonable translation :)